# Deploying rails with capistrano, passenger and apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, deployment, capistrano, passenger

I have recently set up a VPS and am trying to deploy a rails app. I watched a screencast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps which explained how to setup capistrano and unicorn with nginx, but also gave examples for apache.

I followed online guide for setting up passenger and adapted the railscasts capistrano recipe. When I run `cap deploy:setup` some directories are created on my server in the root of the application. Then when I run `cap deploy` the rails app is put into the releases folder and in a directory named by timestamp. So that part seems to work just fine.

So then for a while when i navigated to http://dev.gregchapple.com/site/index I got some passenger errors saying that certain gems were missing, so I installed them on the server using bundler then the errors went away. Thats when the current problem arose. Now when I go to http://dev.gregchapple.com/site/index all it says is: "We're sorry, but something went wrong."

The apache log contains this:

```
cache: [GET /site/index] miss
cache: [GET /] miss
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?
My apache config file has been altered to set the document root to the public directory as specified by the passenger docs. I dont know what the problem is and its driving me insane!

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

## UPDATE

This is what appears the production.log file:

```
Started GET "/site/index" for 109.255.221.170 at 2012-08-06 13:26:13 -0700

Mysql2::Error (Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)):
mysql2 (0.3.11) lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `connect'
mysql2 (0.3.11) lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `initialize'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `new'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `mysql2_connection'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:277:in `new_connection'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:287:in `checkout_new_connection'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:235:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:230:in `loop'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:230:in `block in checkout' /home/greg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:229:in `checkout'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:95:in `connection'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:374:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:168:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:142:in `connection'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:67:in `rescue in call'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:61:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:443:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__3520547282522082875__call__1971459733125288916__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:96:in `process_request'
passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:516:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:274:in `main_loop'
passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:206:in `start_request_handler'
passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:171:in `block in handle_spawn_application'
passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:470:in `safe_fork'
passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:166:in `handle_spawn_application'
passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:129:in `start'
passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:253:in `block (2 levels) in spawn_rack_application'
passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:246:in `block in spawn_rack_application'
passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `block in synchronize'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:244:in `spawn_rack_application'
passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:137:in `spawn_application'
passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
passenger (3.0.15) helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99:in `<main>'
```

## Update 2

### database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: gregchapple_development
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password: *****
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: gregchapple_test
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password: *****
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: gregchapple_production
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password: *****
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Comment: Check your `RAILS_APP/logs/production.log` for errors. Also update your question with the errors so that people can help.

Comment: Just added the contents of production.log - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem like you. I changed these rows in database.yml
add

> host: 127.0.0.1

remove

> socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

Then:

```
cap deploy:setup
cap deploy:check
cap deploy:cold
#some updates with custom code
cap deploy:update
```

You must update everything in code with capistrano, DON'T CHANGE CODE ON VPN (you can create only tmp dir).
You check your sql connection manualy with ssh on vpn. For example

> mysql -u  gregchapple -p

Your virtual host is ok?

Comment: Thank you! It is working for me now! I just changed those values in the production section of `database.yml`. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Your app is looking for the mysql2 adapter, so make sure in your Gemfile you have

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

and that you `bundle install` and that in your `database.yml` file you are using the mysql2 adapter.

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  ...
```

And don't forget to restart Passenger - `touch tmp/restart.txt` from the root of the Rails app.

Congrats!  You're almost there!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I already have that in my gemfile and also in my database.yml file. However I dont have a tmp directory in the root of my app, or a restart.txt file. should that have been created already?

Comment: You'll have to `mkdir tmp` because (as you've discovered) that doesn't already exist.  After that then `touch tmp/restart.txt`.  You'll need to run that command every time you update the filesystem in your Rails app, that'll make Passenger reload the new code.  You should only have to create the `tmp` directory this once though.

Comment: Created `tmp/` and ran `touch tmp/restart.txt` but still showing the error. Do I need to put anything in restart.txt? Thanks for your help

Comment: Bummer.  No, it just needs to be an empty file.  Are you still getting the same error in your production.log? `Mysql2::Error (Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO))`

Comment: No that error is gone now, whats coming up now is `ActionView::Template::Error (application.css isn't precompiled)` do i need to run `rake assets:precompile` ? I thought capistrano was meant to do that..?

Comment: You can either precompile the assets or change the line in config/environments/production.rb `config.assets.compile` from false to true.  Doesn't hurt to change that line regardless, it can save your hide if you forget to precompile.

Answer (score 0):

Your Rails app's `database.yml`'s production section is not configured properly.

1. Configure mysql database on your server.
2. Configure production section in database.yml in your rails app and provide db username and password for production server.
3. Deploy again.
4. Test.

Comment: I just changed the values in `database.yml` to use a different user and the correct password for that user. But the log is still showing up the same as above. What could this be?

Comment: Either you didn't update the production section in database.yml file or the app was not restarted.

Comment: Can you explain what steps I need to do this please? I thought I did it correctly but I guess not. I edited `config/database.yml` on my local computer then pushed to github on development branch (the default for my app) then on the server edited `shared/config/database.yml`. I they ran `cap deploy` on my local and also `git pull` from the server. Still no luck...

Comment: Can you post `RAILS_APP/config/database.yml` here? Hide password before posting.